# dplyr: replace NAs with zeros after group_by, while keeping original NAs in R

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

I am creating a new variable and because of NAs and because only some individuals meet the grouping criteria, I end up with numerous new NAs in my final dataset.

[Here](https://figshare.com/s/ace5b44bc12394a7c46d) is the data.

**UPDATED** Example dataframe:

```
id    age    year   var1
4     KL      2007   15
1     KL      2008   10
2     KL      2008   20
4     AG      2008   NA
3     AG      2008   5    
3     SU      2009   NA
4     SU      2009   NA    
4     LL      2011   NA
```

Dataframe nuances:

1. `age=="KL" & year==2007` has only 1 row (with value)
2. `age=="KL" & year==2008` has multiple rows (with values)
3. `age=="AG" & year==2008` has multiple rows (with values and NAs)
4. `age=="SU" & year==2009` has multiple rows (only with NAs)
5. `age=="LL" & year==2011` has only 1 row (with NA)

Example formula:

```
df<-df %>%
    group_by(age, year) %>% 
    mutate(new_var1=((var1-mean(var1, na.rm=T))/(1*(sd(var1, na.rm=T)))))
```

Current output:

```
id    age    year   var1    new_var1
4     KL      2007   15      NA
1     KL      2008   10     -0.7071068
2     KL      2008   20      0.7071068
4     AG      2008   NA      NA
3     AG      2008   5       NA
3     SU      2009   NA      NA
4     SU      2009   NA      NA
4     LL      2011   NA      NA
```

Desired output:

```
id    age    year   var1    new_var1
4     KL      2007   15      0
1     KL      2008   10     -0.7071068
2     KL      2008   20      0.7071068
4     AG      2008   NA      NA
3     AG      2008   5       0
3     SU      2009   NA      NA
4     SU      2009   NA      NA
4     LL      2011   NA      NA
```

**How can I keep the existing NAs (those are real instances of missing data), while forcing any instances of new NAs (because the row is the only record) to be 0 instead of NA?**

A `dplyr` solution would be greatly appreciated.

I know how to replace NAs with zeros (e.g., `mutate(new_var1=ifelse(is.na(new_var1), 0, new_var1))`), but this replaces all NAs, not just the new NAs.

Comment: what is the ouptut of your last row for id 4

Comment: Like a noob, I hadn't specified the coding for age (it is categorical, not numerical). I've also added the real data to the question.

Comment: It doesn' really matter because we are doing the grouping and the value is computed on numeric

Comment: Hmmm. It must be something really silly on my end. I don't want to waste any more of your time though, so thank you for all your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a condition with `if/else` to check for a single observation and if it is not NA, then return 0 or else do the calculation

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(age, year) %>% 
  mutate(var1 = if(n() == 1 && !is.na(var1) | sum(!is.na(var1)) == 1) 0 * var1
  else ((var1-mean(var1, na.rm=TRUE))/(1*(sd(var1, na.rm=TRUE))))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
     id age    year   var1
  <int> <chr> <int>  <dbl>
1     4 KL     2007  0    
2     1 KL     2008 -0.707
3     2 KL     2008  0.707
4     4 AG     2008 NA    
5     3 AG     2008  0    
6     3 SU     2009 NA    
7     4 SU     2009 NA    
8     4 LL     2011 NA
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), age = c("KL", 
"KL", "KL", "AG", "AG", "SU", "SU", "LL"), year = c(2007L, 2008L, 
2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2011L), var1 = c(15L, 10L, 
20L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: For some reason, when I try to apply your solution, it returns NaN for the whole column. Might you be able to help me troubleshoot why it works for your answer, but not on my end?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist is this based on the same example you showed?  In your original data, I am guessing that there are groups having more than one observation and all of them are NA, which results in `NaN` while you compute with `mean`

Comment: Ah, I think that could be it. I tried to use a condensed example above to not make it overwhelming, but I think that I missed some important nuances?

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist I didn't include that condition here.  Also, there can be cases where there is a single non-NA element and sd can return NA

Comment: I think that is more common in my original dataset (a single non-NA element, which then ends up giving an NA because of the `sd()` function). Would it be possible to modify your answer to allow for those conditions? (I apologize for not asking a better question). I will update my example dataset to try to encompass those things.

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist can you please update with another example so that I won't miss any condition while testing

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist you can just subset your data for those age, year, having the issue along with couple of normal ones and use `dput` to get the struvture

Comment: Updated the dataframe!

Comment: @BlunderingEcologist updated the solution

Comment: I think I'm going to have to post my actual data. One moment.

Comment: May be you still have some other conditions not met

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232666/discussion-between-blundering-ecologist-and-akrun).

Answer (score 0):

An option could be:

```r
df <- structure(list(id = c(4L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), 
                     age = c("KL", "KL", "KL", "AG", "AG", "SU", "SU", "LL"),
                     year = c(2007L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2008L, 2009L, 2009L, 2011L), 
                     var1 = c(15L, 10L, 20L, NA, 5L, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            -8L))
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(age, year) %>% 
  mutate(new_var1=ifelse(is.nan(scale(var1)), 0, scale(var1))) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 8 x 5
#>      id age    year  var1 new_var1[,1]
#>   <int> <chr> <int> <int>        <dbl>
#> 1     4 KL     2007    15        0    
#> 2     1 KL     2008    10       -0.707
#> 3     2 KL     2008    20        0.707
#> 4     4 AG     2008    NA       NA    
#> 5     3 AG     2008     5        0    
#> 6     3 SU     2009    NA       NA    
#> 7     4 SU     2009    NA       NA    
#> 8     4 LL     2011    NA       NA

library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, new_var1 :=ifelse(is.nan(scale(var1)), 0, scale(var1)), by = list(age, year)][]
#>    id age year var1   new_var1
#> 1:  4  KL 2007   15  0.0000000
#> 2:  1  KL 2008   10 -0.7071068
#> 3:  2  KL 2008   20  0.7071068
#> 4:  4  AG 2008   NA         NA
#> 5:  3  AG 2008    5  0.0000000
#> 6:  3  SU 2009   NA         NA
#> 7:  4  SU 2009   NA         NA
#> 8:  4  LL 2011   NA         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>